# How can we set the name of the email sender in Rails Mailer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, mandrill

Whenever I send an email through my Rails app, in my inbox, the name of the sender is shown as "admin".. The email is admin@... The first part of the domain is shown. Im using Mandrill to send the email. How can I change this name?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

If you're using ActionMailer, try below

```
mail(
  from: 'Sender Name <sender@example.com>', 
  to: 'Receiver Name <receiver@example.com>', 
  subject: 'Subject'
)
```

If you're using the Mandrill API, you can explicitly set the sender name API call payload

Answer (score 19):

This work for me(Rails):

```
default(

   from: "SenderName <hola@udocz.com>",
   reply_to: "SenderName <hola@udocz.com>"

)

def send_mail(email, subject)

   #body = ......

   mail(to: email, subject: subject, body: body, content_type: "text/html")

end
```

Answer (score 5):

I've used this solution from the [ActionMailer guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#sending-email-with-name) and it works perfectly.

```
class AdminMailer < ApplicationMailer
    default from: email_address_with_name('admin@example.com', 'Admin Name')
end
```

Comment: `email_address_with_name` method is only available in Rails version >6.1.x